# Calling a script with ./bla.sh vs. . bla.sh

Tags: unix, bash, script

Can anybody explain to me what the shell does in the two examples A) and B) below?
It obviously behaves differently, but I can't find out why the output is different.

Example:
Let's have a script in our current directory named `bla.sh` with only one command:
`echo ${0##/*} hello`

A)
Started as: `./bla.sh`
gives: `./bla.sh hello`

B)
Started as: `. bla.sh`
gives: `-bash hello`

Since I use this in a script, the second output (because of the "-" in front of the -bash) kills the command. Of course, a simple `--` before the `${...}` helped, but I would love to understand what causes the output in the first place.
I love bash. And vi[m]. But I digress…

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
./bla.sh
```

Here, the command is `./bla.sh`. This makes the shell look for an executable named `bla.sh` in the current directory, then ask the kernel to run it as a normal program, in a separate process from the shell. (It doesn't matter if `bla.sh` is a `bash` script, a `perl` or `python` one, or a compiled binary.)

---

```
. bla.sh
```

Here, the command is `.` (aka `source`), a built-in command of your shell. It makes the shell look for a file named `bla.sh` in the system path ($PATH) and interpret the contents as if they were typed by you; all this is done in the *same process* as the shell itself (and therefore can affect the shell's internal state).

This of course only works when `bla.sh` contains commands for the `bash` shell (if that's the one you are currently using), it won't work for `perl` scripts or anything else.

(This is explained in `help .` and `help source` too.)

---

As `.` and `./` are completely different things (a command vs part of a path), they can be combined, of course – using `. ./bla.sh` would "source" a file `bla.sh` in the current directory.

---

Usually it is best to use the `./bla.sh` method. Only `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and such files are usually sourced, because they are supposed to modify the current environment.

Comment: Moreover, if you change bash environment in bla.sh, these changes are taken into account after . bla.sh but not after ./bla.sh. this is because . bla.sh runs in the context of the current bash whereas ./bla.sh runs as a subprocess.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060 for some examples. Note that `source` is a bash alias for `.`, not the contrary and `source` won't work in other shells.

Answer (score 7):

`./<cmd>` will execute the `<cmd>` program that resides in the current directory in a new (forked) process. It has to be executable. And also readable it starts with `#!`.

`. <cmd>` will make your current shell execute the shell script `<cmd>` that resides in your `$PATH` or the current directory in the *current* shell process. It has to be readable. It is an alias for the shell command `source`.

Comment: -1 `. <cmd>` will look for the program in `$PATH` and if it is not found THEN it will look in the current directory.

Comment: @dogbane Right, I corrected this.

Comment: FWIW, not all shells will search cwd for sourced sripts. zsh (at least with the config I have) requires `. ./cmd`

Comment: @bstpierre This seem to be a moving ground. The POSIX reference I have says that “the shell shall use the search path specified by PATH” and “Some older implementations searched the current directory for the file, even if the value of PATH disallowed it.”

Answer (score 1):

`./cmd`  uses explicit path (`./` - current dir) to executable.  And it is not necessary that it starts with `#!`.

`. cmd` - (aka `source`) - bash builtin command. One visible difference of executing through `source` is that it can set/modify environment variable of current shell.

Comment: more precisely, `source` is a bash-only alias to `.` (which is standard)

Comment: You are right. Fixed.