# What are the differences between "sh file.sh" and "source file.sh"?

Tags: shell

I am trying to set up a cron job to run regression tests for software that usually runs in an interactive environment (CASA, for the morbidly curious: http://casa.nrao.edu/).  I have a shell script, which, in MWE form (`mwe.sh`), does:

```
casapy -c mwe.py
```

where it is supposed to execute that script.  `casapy` is a fairly complicated bit of business that does a lot of things internally, including importing and setting up an ipython client for multiprocessing.

Here is my problem:
If I run the code interactively, i.e. type `casapy -c mwe.py` on the bash shell command line, it works.
If I run:

```
source mwe.sh
```

the code still runs exactly as expected and performs the tests.  Great!

If instead, I run

```
bash mwe.sh
```

the startup script hangs permanently.  I've tracked this down to a few different locations in the startup script that all are capable of independently failing.

So, my question: What are the differences between starting commands in the interactive shell environment and from within a script?  Especially, what are the differences that can be narrowed down to differences between `source file.sh` and `sh file.sh`?

In particular, in the context of the cron job I'm trying to run, is there any way to do the equivalent of `source`ing a file on the interactive command line?

EDIT: one last piece of information - I think this failure only happens on mac, not on linux, but I don't know if that provides any useful information at all because the underlying code is somewhat different for the two platforms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a script with ./bla.sh vs. . bla.sh](http://superuser.com/questions/40456/calling-a-script-with-bla-sh-vs-bla-sh)

Answer (score 3):

`source foo.sh` runs the script in [the *current Bash shell*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Sourcing), very similar to simply replacing the `source foo.sh` command by the contents of the `foo.sh` file. `sh foo.sh` runs the script within the context of a *new `sh` shell*, which on many OSes is not even Bash (which may be one reason the script doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks.  In the context of the question, though, I'm still trying to understand what difference could cause my code to crash.  Are there any differences besides the environment variables?  (as I've now indicated, the shell is the same, `bash`, in both cases)

Answer (score 1):

The differences between starting commands in the interactive shell environment or from within a script is the environment.

To see the differences between `source foo.sh` and `sh foo.sh` you have to know what happens in either way:

1. `source foo.sh`:

`source` is a bash-only built-in command. That means when you call `source`, there is no executable like `/bin/source` or so. `bash` itself parses the command-line interface for so called [shell builtin commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html). The `source` command is a builtin function of `bash` to ...

> read  and  execute  commands from filename **in the current shell
>   environment** and return the exit status of the last command executed
>   from filename.

So, it's like when you just copy and paste line by line of your `foo.sh` file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after every line. When no `bash` is running, then there is also no `source` command.

2. `sh foo.sh`:

This call the default shell `/bin/sh` with an argument, a [command_file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html). That is a  pathname of a file containing commands. That file need not be executable. And there is also no necessarity of a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line in it. So, a **new** shell is started (`/bin/sh`) and in that new shell, the command in the file are executed line by line. But, now the environment is **not the current shell environment**. It's the environment generated by the shell.

Comment: Thanks.  Are there any differences besides the generated environment?  The only different environment variables I can see are `SHLVL` and `TMPDIR`.  I can't figure out any reason these variables would affect the script I'm running.